# Division By 0 error when running an update query MySQL

Tags: mysql, update, errors

I am trying to run an update in a table and I get an **"Error Code: 1365. Division by 0"**. The sql commands I use are these:

```
SET @@autocommit = 0;
start transaction;
update XE_General
join Locations
on XE_General.url_location = Locations.url_location
set 
XE_General.neighborhood = Locations.neighborhood_GR,
XE_General.municipality = Locations.municipality_GR,
XE_General.zipcode = Locations.zipcode 
where XE_General.zipcode is null
and XE_General.neighborhood is null
and XE_General.municipality is null;
```

I do not use division anywhere in the query and I have checked that rows which satisfy the where conditions indeed exist.

What could be the cause of this error? Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have triggers that could be dividing by zero when you update?

Comment: Are either of those "Tables" actually /Views/ that might contain such calculations?

Comment: @WillemRenzema  there is one generated column in the XE_General table which uses division. Is this somehow related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a generated column that is [STORED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html), then

> Column values are evaluated and stored when rows are inserted or
> updated. A stored column does require storage space and can be
> indexed.

This would explain the why the error occurs while updating. Whatever values you are setting can cause the generated column to divide by zero at the same time as the update.